# DataGrid Does not seem to allow editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using a "WebForm" Datagrid.

DataGrid is bound to a dataset and shows data.

Based on my findings to make DataGrid Editable All I need to do is 
to add an Editcommandcolumn.

I did that, so I have:

```
<asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
```

Now the datagrid shows a new column with a hyperlink "EDIT" in the first coulmn.

The problem is nothing happens when I click on Edit on any row.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post your DataGrid control code? I think that you are missing the <EditItemTemplate>...

Comment: Good question, My DataGrid has little Html, It is bound to a dataset. Trying to make it editable I clicked on it's properties and added a Button Control(Edit,update,Cancel)

The generated HTML code is this:
<asp:DataGrid id="dg" runat="server" Width="288px" Height="160px">
  <Columns>
     <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton"   UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Click to Edit" CancelText="Cancel"
      EditText="Edit"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
   </asp:DataGrid>

Comment: So no, I don't see a <EditItemTemplate> tag in HTML

Comment: First, put your code in your question (editing it), not inside comments. And how are you binding the datagrid?

Comment: By the way, do you have any framework restriction to be using the DataGrid in place of the GridView?

Comment: Yes I do have Restriction. I'm limited to framework 1.1

Comment: I can't use any Grid newer than DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just made an example that it is working.

First I have my DataGrid definition:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" DataKeyField="DatasetField1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" OnCancelCommand="Grid_CancelCommand" OnEditCommand="Grid_EditCommand" OnUpdateCommand="Grid_UpdateCommand">
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Column1" DataField="DatasetField1"></asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Column2" DataField="DatasetField2"></asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
 </Columns>
```

Second I must bind my data grid:

```
public BindData()
{
    ....
    Grid.DataSource = [MyDataSet With DatasetFiel1 and DatasetField2 fields];
    Grid.DataBind();
}
```

Third I handle the editting events (look in the DataGrid markup above):

*An event for when you click the Edit link button inside the grid:*

```
protected void Grid_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Grid.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

*An event for when you click the Cancel link button after editting. Just to cancel the changes:*

```
protected void Grid_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

*Finally an event when you confirm your editting values:*

```
protected void Grid_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you save your changes to the database
}
```

Let me know if you have any issue...

Comment: Excellent Job! It works. You have my upvote and also acception.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have code that allow put a Dropdownlist in a editable column?